# an unclear definition about the types of phrase-structure grammars

Tags: discrete-mathematics, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I am reading the book "Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications" written by Kenneth Rosen. I've encountered some troubles.

When it introduced the type-2 of phrase-structure grammar to me, it just told me the productions should only have the form *A → γ*, where *A* is a single symbol that is not a terminal symbol. So what about *γ* and can it have the production *S → λ* without any restriction?
Second, it showed me an example, it constructed a grammar *G=(V,T,S,P)* to generate the set {0<sup>n</sup>1<sup>n</sup>2<sup>n</sup>∣ n = 0,1,2,3,…}, where *V = {0,1,2,S,A,B,C}*; *T = {0,1,2}*; starting state *S*; and productions *P={S → C, C → 0CAB, S → , BA → AB, 0A → 01, 1A → 11, 1B → 12, 2B → 22}*. And it told me such grammar G is a context-sensitive grammar, that is, type 1 grammar. I think it is wrong. First, I think the productions P is incorrect, the term *S →*  should be *C → λ*, or the term *C → 0CAB* should be *C → 0SAB*, otherwise the nonterminal *C* would always exist. And then, the grammar would not be type 1 grammar, because *γ* in *αAβ→αγβ* cannot be empty and *S→λ* allowed only if *S* never appear on the right-hand of any production. Am I right?